# Вывод точки у последнего элемента

Tags: php

Как сделать так, чтобы у последнего элемента в массиве не выводилась запятая, а выводилась точка?

```
while($arFields = $res->Fetch()){
    echo $arFields["NAME"].", ";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Если массив убирается в оперативную память скрипта, можно поступить следующим образом

```
<?php
$arr = array();
while($arFields = $res->Fetch()){
    $arr[] = $arFields["NAME"];
}
if(count($arr) > 0) {
    echo implode(", ", $arr).".";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "";
while($arFields = $res->Fetch()){
    $string .= $arFields["NAME"].", ";
}
echo rtrim($string, ", ").".";
```

Comment: лучше `rtrim()`, а то пострадает первое имя, которое (вдруг?) начинается с ", "

Answer (score 1):

выводите запятую **перед** очередным, а после всего добавьте точку:

```
$first = true;
while($arFields = $res->Fetch()){
    echo ($first ? '' : ', ') . $arFields["NAME"];
    $first = false;
}
echo '.';
```